# Python: Download CSV file from URL which is part of a json response

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests

I am trying to download a file using Python from a URL
When I invoke the GET API, it gives a json response in output
How do I extract the file from the json in CSV format ?

Following is the code I used:

```
header = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + my_token }
resp = requests.get(fileURL, headers=header)
my_file = resp.json()['files']['file']
open("my_file_name.csv", "wb").write(resp.content)
```

This is what I get as output inside my_file_name.csv -

```
{"files":{"file":"77u/","fileName":"Contact history disposition Controls_20230519T054023.csv"}}
```

This is the value of fileURL variable: https://api-c33.nice-incontact.com/inContactAPI/services/V28.0/files?fileName=CustomReports%5cApiReports%5cContact+history+disposition+Controls_20230521T222043.csv

Comment: It does not appear to actually contain the file. The `file` and `fileName` parts are probably part of a URL where the file is actually hosted. The answer to this depends on which API you're using.

Comment: Its the NICE In-contact API.. this is the value of fileURL variable - https://api-c33.nice-incontact.com/inContactAPI/services/V28.0/files?fileName=CustomReports%5cApiReports%5cContact+history+disposition+Controls_20230521T222043.csv

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this API endpoint?

Comment: Thanks Nick, you showed me the right path to resolve this. I checked the documentation and found that the report job filetype parameter was not set properly in the UI (it should be CSV but was set as XLS). The above code now works properly, I just had to replace "resp.content" to "my_file"

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation and found that the report job filetype parameter was not set properly in the UI (it should be CSV but was set as XLS). The above code now works properly, I just had to replace "resp.content" to "my_file"